# Removing the end of line character from a read csv file

Tags: python, csv, newline, strip

I tried sever times to use `strip()` but I can't get it to work.
I removed that piece from this snip but every time I tried it I had
an error or it did nothing. The sort is fine I just want to strip the newline before writing to the new file?

```
import sys, csv, operator
data = csv.reader(open('tickets.csv'),delimiter=',')
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(6))
# 0 specifies according to first column we want to sort

#now write the sort result into new CSV file
 
with open("newfiles.csv", "w") as f:
    #writablefile = csv.writer(f)
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in sortedlist:
        #print(row)
        lst = (row)
        fileWriter.writerow(lst)
```

Comment: Update the question to put the strip back in.  Otherwise we don't know how you tried to do it, and so we can't point out what you did wrong.

Comment: Does your CSV file have a header?  I looks like it will include that in the sort

Comment: Instead of the loop, you could try `fileWriter.writerows(sortedlist)`

Comment: it has a header and I did try that fileWriter.writerows(sortedlist) but that does not remove the new line. - Thanks

Comment: @Kevin `That was it!` states an answer as accepted. Please read and follow the [tour] and accept or upvote! This is how SO keeps contributers motivated to answer (your) questions 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `newline=''` to your `open()` when writing a CSV file. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer). Without it, your file can end up having a blank line per row.

```
import sys, csv, operator

data = csv.reader(open('tickets.csv'),delimiter=',')
header = next(data)

sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(6))
# 0 specifies according to first column we want to sort

#now write the sort result into a new CSV file
with open("newfiles.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f)
    
    fileWriter.writerow(header)     # keep the header at the top
    fileWriter.writerows(sortedlist)
```

Also you need to first read in the header row before loading everything for sorting. This avoids it being sorted. It can then be output separately when writing your sorted output CSV.

If your `tickets.csv` file contains blank lines, you would need to also remove these. For example:

```
    for row in sortedList:
        if row:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: That was it! Than you very much.